# I am using Entity Framework I want to Add date and time i am getting date from front end and than just concatenation with time

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework I want to add date and time. I am getting date from front end and than just concatenation with time

```
 datetime dt = dtstring//31/Mar/2015
```

then add

```
time tm = '12:00:00:000'
```

and after insert data in SQL as

```
'2015-03-31 12:00:00:000', '2015-03-31 11:59:59:000'
```

Comment: Can you mention what is your Model, and what datatype you are using in database?

Answer (score 2):

```
string one = "31/Mar/2015";
string two = "12:00:00:000";    

DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(one + " " + two, "dd/MMM/yyyy h:mm:ss:fff",      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(dt1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss:fff"));
```

Comment: date in format as mm/dd/yyyy => 03/31/2015 so error throw string is not valid datetime

Comment: string one="31/mar/2015" so it throw error so please again check it

Comment: it was typo mm instead of MM check it.. and mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

In C#

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date;
        TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(1, 10, 30); // time to be added
        long ticks = time.Ticks;
        now = now.AddTicks(ticks);
```

Comment: Got Solution Thanks For Both pradip and @Brain Coder